# Is this ok with the strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c++, c++11, strict-aliasing

```
struct Test {
    void doAction() {}
};

// Create and save into a void*
void *ptr = new Test;

// Real use through a Test*
Test *t = static_cast<Test *>(ptr);
t->doAction();

// Delete
delete static_cast<Test *>(ptr);
```

ptr is used only to save the address of the object, and the address is only dereferenced to the true type of the object.

So unless it is dereferenced to an unrelated type, it's ok with the strict aliasing rule ?

Comment: Compile using GCC with -fstrict-aliasing

Comment: Yes, it is fine, as long as you know you are casting into right type. As an aside, you would find this being done in lots of places where C++ code interacts with C code (mainly in asynchronous callbacks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strict aliasing only applies when you are attempting to access the object through a pointer/reference. You are not attempting to access the object through a `void*`, so the strict aliasing rule doesn't even apply (the rule that protects you here is the rule on `static_cast` that allows it to convert a pointer to any type to `void*` and back, so long as the type you cast it back to is *exactly* the type it was before).

Similarly, pointers to the same type are allowed to alias. So `t` and the result of `static_cast<T*>` are allowed to alias and thus having both do not violate strict aliasing.